# Image is not showing according to the frame of UIImage after zooming and rotating

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I add pinch to zoom and rotate gestures to UIImageView (myImageView). After zooming and rotating, there is apply button to save the image. Below is the apply method. It saves the image correctly with exact rotation and scaling . As it is just like screenshot.

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size,view.opaque,0.0);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData *data=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(viewImage, 100);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *strPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"BorderedImage.jpg"];
[data writeToFile:strPath atomically:YES];
```

But after doing this , i reassign the saved image to myImageView.

```
myImageView.image=[self loadImage:@"BorderedImage.jpg"];
```

what it does, if image was zoomed out , image becomes more small, if image was zoomed in , image  becomes too big. if image was rotated, then image shows with totally wrong rotation .

I know this is some kind of UIImageView problem, because i checked the image in documents folder , it is same just like when i press apply button.

i am new to iOS development . kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

After a great headache , i solved it myself. just before re-assigning the transformed image, i change the UIImageView transform to the original transform values.

```
myImageView.transform=defaultTranform;
```

where defaultTransform is

```
CGAffineTransform rotTran; 
rotTran=myImageView.transform; // view did load
```